# Conditional join large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes having over 20K rows each.

DF 1

```
index  Number   From_Date    To_Date
 0      1212     05/03/21    05/05/21
 1      1213     05/04/21    05/09/21
 2      1213     05/08/21    05/12/21
 3      1215     05/13/21    05/15/21
 4      1216     05/16/21    05/23/21
```

DF 2

```
index  Number    Date        Delivered
 0      1212     05/04/21    True
 1      1213     05/05/21    True
 2      1214     05/07/21    False
 3      1212     05/19/21    True
 4      1216     05/30/21    True
```

Now I want to add new column in DF1 `Delivered` if the Number from DF1 exists in DF2 and the Date is between From_Date and To_Date.
I have Tried using DF apply and Looping through DF and Filtering out row from DF2 in the loop but its taking around 2 minute to finish.
I want to have a fast and clean approach for this.

Expected output

DF 1

```
index  Number   From_Date    To_Date     Delivered
 0      1212     05/03/21    05/05/21     Yes
 1      1213     05/04/21    05/09/21     Yes
 2      1213     05/08/21    05/12/21     No 
 3      1215     05/13/21    05/15/21     No
 4      1216     05/16/21    05/23/21     No
```

Comment: Are the values in `Number` in DF2 uniq?

Comment: No, values of number can be duplicate.

Comment: Kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: Can't you just `merge` the two dfs and then check whether `Date` is between from and to?

Comment: @sammywemmy expected result added in question.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', left_on = 'Number', right_on = 'Number')
df['Delivered'] = (df['Date'] >= df['From_Date']) & (df['Date'] <= df['To_Date'])
```

if this is still taking too long, consider using pySpark instead of pandas.

Comment: the Number can be duplicate on both dataframe.

Comment: hence merging and filtering, this method should resolve any potential issue. otherwise, if there is a problem with it, if you could present an example where it doesn't work?